# SignalR. An HTTP/2 connection could not be established

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, iis-8, signalr.client, asp.net-core-signalr

I have SignalR server (hub) and C# client.

Target Framework: net6.0.

The server uses let's encrypt certificates.

After upgrading SignalR client from 6.0.10 to 7.0.12, the error "An HTTP/2 connection could not be established because the server did not complete the HTTP/2 handshake" appeared on one of the client computers (Windows Server 2012 R2).

Error occurs when calling `StartAsync`

```cs
_hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder().WithUrl($"{_setting.HubUrl}/hubs/tariff")
  .AddJsonProtocol(options => options.PayloadSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null).Build();
await _hubConnection.StartAsync(); // <-- Exception HttpRequestException
```

There are no errors when testing local client.
How to fix this problem?
Maybe there are options to forcefully disable http/2?

Stacktrace:

> ! An HTTP/2 connection could not be established because the server did not complete the HTTP/2 handshake.
> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An HTTP/2 connection could not be established because the server did not complete the HTTP/2 handshake.
> at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ReturnHttp2Connection(Http2Connection connection, Boolean isNewConnection)
> at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.AddHttp2ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request)
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.AsyncStateMachineBox`1.ExecutionContextCallback(Object s)
> at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.AsyncStateMachineBox`1.MoveNext(Thread threadPoolThread)
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.AsyncStateMachineBox`1.MoveNext()
> at System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.RunOrScheduleAction(IAsyncStateMachineBox box, Boolean allowInlining)
> at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.RunContinuations(Object continuationObject)
> at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.TrySetResult(TResult result) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncValueTaskMethodBuilder`1.SetResult(TResult result)
> at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.AsyncStateMachineBox`1.ExecutionContextCallback(Object s)
> at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.AsyncStateMachineBox`1.MoveNext(Thread threadPoolThread)
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.AsyncStateMachineBox`1.MoveNext()
> at System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.RunOrScheduleAction(IAsyncStateMachineBox box, Boolean allowInlining)
> at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.RunContinuations(Object continuationObject)
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.SetExistingTaskResult(Task`1 task, TResult result)
> at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsync(SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Stream stream, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.AsyncStateMachineBox`1.ExecutionContextCallback(Object s)
> at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.AsyncStateMachineBox`1.MoveNext(Thread threadPoolThread)
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.AsyncStateMachineBox`1.MoveNext()
> at System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.RunOrScheduleAction(IAsyncStateMachineBox box, Boolean allowInlining)
> at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.RunContinuations(Object continuationObject)
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.SetExistingTaskResult(Task`1 task, TResult result)
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.SetResult()
> at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ForceAuthenticationAsync[TIOAdapter](TIOAdapter adapter, Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] reAuthenticationData, Boolean isApm)
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.AsyncStateMachineBox`1.ExecutionContextCallback(Object s)
> at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.AsyncStateMachineBox`1.MoveNext(Thread threadPoolThread)
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.AsyncStateMachineBox`1.MoveNext()
> at System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.RunOrScheduleAction(IAsyncStateMachineBox box, Boolean allowInlining)
> at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.RunContinuations(Object continuationObject)
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.SetExistingTaskResult(Task`1 task, TResult result)
> at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ReceiveBlobAsync[TIOAdapter](TIOAdapter adapter)
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.AsyncStateMachineBox`1.ExecutionContextCallback(Object s)
> at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.AsyncStateMachineBox`1.MoveNext(Thread threadPoolThread)
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.AsyncStateMachineBox`1.MoveNext()
> at System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.RunOrScheduleAction(IAsyncStateMachineBox box, Boolean allowInlining)
> at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.RunContinuations(Object continuationObject)
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncValueTaskMethodBuilder`1.SetResult(TResult result) at System.Net.Security.SslStream.<FillHandshakeBufferAsync>g__InternalFillHandshakeBufferAsync|189_0[TIOAdapter](TIOAdapter adap, ValueTask`1 task, Int32 minSize)
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.AsyncStateMachineBox`1.ExecutionContextCallback(Object s)
> at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.AsyncStateMachineBox`1.MoveNext(Thread threadPoolThread)
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.AsyncStateMachineBox`1.MoveNext()
> at System.Threading.ThreadPool.<>c.<.cctor>b__87_0(Object state)
> at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.InvokeContinuation(Action`1 continuation, Object state, Boolean forceAsync, Boolean requiresExecutionContextFlow) at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.OnCompleted(SocketAsyncEventArgs _) at System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* pNativeOverlapped) --- End of stack trace from previous location --- at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSourceWithCancellation`1.WaitWithCancellationAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.GetHttp2ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithVersionDetectionAndRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.Internal.AccessTokenHttpMessageHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.Internal.LoggingHttpMessageHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.g__Core|83_0(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts, CancellationTokenSource pendingRequestsCts, CancellationToken originalCancellationToken)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnection.NegotiateAsync(Uri url, HttpClient httpClient, ILogger logger, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnection.GetNegotiationResponseAsync(Uri uri, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnection.SelectAndStartTransport(TransferFormat transferFormat, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnection.StartAsyncCore(TransferFormat transferFormat, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnection.StartAsync(TransferFormat transferFormat, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnectionFactory.ConnectAsync(EndPoint endPoint, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnectionFactory.ConnectAsync(EndPoint endPoint, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.HubConnection.StartAsyncCore(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.HubConnection.StartAsyncInner(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.HubConnection.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at ...

Answer (score 0):

[The IIS version is 8.5 in Windows Server 2012 R2.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/install/installing-iis-85/installing-iis-85-on-windows-server-2012-r2)

And [the HTTP/2 Support was introduced in IIS 10.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-10/http2-on-iis) ( Windows Server 2016 +).

[image]

**Solution**

1. So you need to upgrade the windows server system.
2. If you don't want to upgrade it, you can think about using NGINX.

> It acts as a front-end reverse proxy, accepting HTTP/2 connections and forwarding them as HTTP/1.1 connections to your backend server. This allows clients to connect to NGINX using HTTP/2, while your application server (such as one running on Windows Server 2012 R2) still uses HTTP/1.1.

Comment: SignalR Hub is running as docker container on linux server (Ubuntu 20.04.5).
SignalR client is running on Windows Server 2012 R2.
So IIS is not used.

Comment: Hi @Aries Which kind of web server you are using ? Kestrel，NGINX，Apache ？ We need to check the settings about  HTTP/2 .

Comment: I use Kestrel server

Comment: Hi @Aries Could you share your code in Program.cs file about the `builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel` ？

Comment: This is a typical configuration:

Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
  .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) => {
    config.AddJsonFile("Gateway.appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: false);
})

But I want to point out that the problem occurs on a specific client machine. And, for example, the connection from the local SignalR client passes without errors.